# Is there a better way to calculate the number of codewords of weight $i$ in a list of codewords?

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, counting

**Background Info**

I am interested in a better way of doing the following:

I want to find the weights of the following codewords (the weight of a codeword here can be defined as the number of nonzero entries in that codeword e.g the weight of the codeword (1,0,1,1) would be 3):

```
{{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1}}
```

The weights of these codewords would be 0,1,1 and 2 respectively.

Let $A_{i}$ denote the number of codewords with weight $i$.

So for this example, there is one codeword of weight $0$ so $A_{0}=1$

There are two codewords of weight $1$, so $A_{1}=2$

There is one codeword of weight $2$, so $A_{2}=1$

**My attempt**

Define the codewords and their respective weights

```
In[1]= codewords = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}
In[2]= weights = Total[codewords[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[codewords]]

Out[1]= {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}
Out[2]= {0, 1, 1, 2}
```

Now define $A_{i}$ as being the number of codewords of weight $i$

```
In[3]= A0 = Length[If[weights[[#]] == 0, 0, Nothing] & /@ Range[Length[weights]]]
In[4]= A1 = Length[If[weights[[#]] == 1, 1, Nothing] & /@ Range[Length[weights]]]
In[5]= A2 = Length[If[weights[[#]] == 2, 2, Nothing] & /@ Range[Length[weights]]]

Out[3]= 1
Out[4]= 2
Out[5]= 1
```

The above code works, but there must be a more elegant solution, perhaps one that doesn't need so much manual interference. If anyone has a better idea, please let me know!

Comment: Just a pedagogical note... One nice thing about `Map` is that you don't need to keep track of indices yourself. So, in your solution, you can replace `weights = Total[codewords[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[codewords]]` with `weights = Total /@ codewords`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `GroupBy`:**

```
codewords = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}};
GroupBy[codewords, Total, Length]
```

> <|0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1|>

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment on the nice pieces of Mathematica code suggested by the other answerers, but as a (former) coding theorist I want to remark that people working in this area often use a generating function ([a weight enumerator polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerator_polynomial)) for storing and manipulating this kind of information.

If we denote the Hamming weight of a word $r$ by $w(r)$, the weight enumerating polynomial $W_C(x)$ of a code $C$ of length $n$ is simply
$$
W_C(x):=\sum_{r\in C}x^{w(r)}=\sum_{i=0}^nA_ix^i,
$$
where, for all $i$ in the range $0\le i\le n$, $A_i$ is the number of words of weight $i$.

With my very vanilla skills in Mathematica-coding it could go as follows (assuming binary codes only):

```
Weight[r_] := Sum[r[[i]], {i, 1, Length[r]}]
WeightEnumerator[C_] := Sum[x^Weight[C[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[C]}]
```

So for example

```
codewords = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
WeightEnumerator[codewords]
```

gives the output

```
1 + 2 x^2 + x^4
```

meaning that there was one word of weight zero, two of weight two and one of weight four.

Comment: `GroupBy[codewords, Total, Length] // 
  KeyValueMap[#2 x^#1 &, #] & // Total`

Comment: This is fantastic. I had wanted to move on to checking that Ai and Bi satisfy the MacWilliams identity, so this is a great jumping off point for that!

Comment: @QC123_367 Please compare this (performancewise) with the snippet Syed suggested. They know more about Mathematica-programming than I ever will, so for larger codes theirs is likely the faster method. For MacWilliams identity you may prefer to use the two variable version. If we denote by $f(x)$ the polynomial my snippet produces, the two variable version is $W_C(x,y)=f(x/y)*y^n$. MacWilliams is usually written using that polynomial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen have indeed used Syed's code. And yes, thank you, I have used the two variable version for MacWilliams identity. I adapted Syed's code so that the two variable weight enumerator polynomial looked something like:
 Module[{n, weightenumerator},
 n = Length[codewords[[1]]];
  weightenumerator = GroupBy[codewords2, Total, Length] // KeyValueMap[#2 x^(n - #1) y^#1 &, #] & // Total;
  weightenumerator]

Which outputs $x^{4} + 2x^{3}y + x^{2}y^{2}$

Answer (score 2):

```
codewords = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}

a = Count[1] /@ codewords
```

{0, 1, 1, 2}

```
b = Counts @ a
```

<|0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1|>

```
Values[b]
```

{1, 2, 1}

Assignment to variables as per your question:

```
{A0, A1, A2} = Values[b];
```

Better in my opinion

```
A = Values[b];
```

with `Part` syntax:

```
A[[2]]
```

2

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
codewords = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

and assuming that all letters are either 0 or 1, you could do this:

```
weightCounts = CountsBy[codewords, Total]
(* <|0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1|> *)
```

Now `weightCounts` corresponds to your `A` and would work almost exactly like you want:

```
weightCounts[0] (* 1 *)
weightCounts[1] (* 2 *)
weightCounts[2] (* 1 *)
```

If there are more than just the two letters 0,1, and if only nonzero letters count for weight, then you could replace the above assignment to `weightCounts` with any of these that fit your scenario:

```
weightCounts = CountsBy[codewords, Length@*DeleteCases[0]]
weightCounts = CountsBy[codewords, Count[_?Positive]]
weightCounts = CountsBy[codewords, Count[_?(# != 0 &)]]
```